# supremum of family of increasing linear type function

Tags: real-analysis, monotone-functions

If we assume $f_{i}(x)=\langle x^*,x \rangle +c \| x\|$ 's are monotone increasing functions, does taking the supremum of these functions over $i \in I$ yield monotone increasing functions?
I assume with $x_{1} \leq  x_{2}$ then we have $f_{i}(x_{1})\leq f_{i}(x_{2})$ for all $i \in I$, since $f_{i}$ s are continuous we can take the supremum of both sides over i then it yields the result ? Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, you don't need anything about 'linear type'.

Comment: i mean it is a piecewise function passing through the origin

Comment: Supemum of **any** family of increasing functions is increasing. Why bring in special type of functions unnecessarily?

Comment: apart from that, until now there is no $i$-dependence whatsoever

Comment: if it is infimum of any family of increasing functions,  is that still an increasing function ?